# polymer string concatenation for template repeat in v 1.0

Tags: polymer

I'm not sure if the following is possible with a "computed" and a dom-repeat template. I was binding with child and parent properties prior to .9/.8/1.0

```
<template is="dom-repeat" as="agreementTypeCount" index-as="agreementTypeCountI" items="{{agreementTypeCounts}}">
  <a href="/{{style_domain}}/agreements/#/table/country/{{selectedCountryCode}}/type/{{agreementTypeCount.type}}/sort/start-desc/size/10/page/1/">{{agreementTypeCount.type}}</a>
</template>
```

Are there any plans to implement string concatenation? It would make life **so** much easier!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's currently on the roadmap. However you can also use computed bindings for this.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" as="agreementTypeCount" index-as="agreementTypeCountI" items="{{agreementTypeCounts}}">
  <a href$="{{computeAgreementUrl(style_domain, selectedCountryCode, agreementTypeCount.type)}}">{{agreementTypeCount.type}}</a>
</template>
```

and then declare it

```
Polymer({
  ...
  computeAgreementUrl(styleDomain, countryCode, type){
    return "/"+styleDomain+"/agreements/#/table/country/"+countryCode+"/type/"+type+"/sort/start-desc/size/10/page/1/";
  }
})
```

Please take note of the $ character next to href. It is recommended that you use attribute binding ($=) to native elements' attributes.

Comment: Thank you, that isn't too much of a rewrite. Any idea of a time frame for string concatenation(weeks, months)? I have a 5.x project and use string concatenation everywhere, without having it the migration because much more difficult. So I am not sure if I should wait for string concat or bite the bullet and dive on in...

Comment: They mentioned it on their site that they'll be working on it post 1.0. So soon perhaps? Might be before the Polymer Summit this September.

Comment: The issue tracking string concat/interpolation is here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2182